# TYPO3 page structure depending on grand parent page

Tags: typo3

I have a set of content pages called a,b,c,d,e. All of them can be seen from three aspects X,Y,Z. And then there are some categories 1,2,3 that define, which content pages should be shown in that category. So there would be a page tree like this:

```
1
 - X
    - a
    - b
 - Y
    - c
    - d
 - Z
    - e
2
 - X
    - a
    - c
 - Y
    - c
    - d
    - e
 - Z
    - a
    - d
3
 - X
    - e
 - Y
    - d
 - Z
    - b
    - c
```

Note that the content pages are the same in every category. They just come in different combinations according to the category.

To minimize redundancy, I am looking for a decent way to arrange that content. The plan is to place the actual content pages a,b,c,d,e in some system folder and shortcut them in X,Y,Z.

My problem is how to solve the redundancy of X,Y,Z . Right now I would have a total of nine page items for the different aspects, that name equal and have equal page content. Just the subpages differ according to the grand parent page. Is there a way to solve that in TYPO3 4?

Is there a way in TYPO3 6, so that an upgrade might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Mount point" page type (doktype) to construct your navigation. It takes the content from another page and shows it at another place in the navigation (not just linking to it like a shortcut). I think that's what you're looking for.

No need to upgrade TYPO3 for that feature.

This is OK for a small site.

If your structure will grow, you might start thinking of creating your menu differently. This is probably some "aspect-oriented" navigation type. So you might either quit thinking in "Pages" and see it more like a database you filter and display by tags or categories. You could build a custom extension for that or abuse the news extension (well.. don't), or try something like the "browser" extension.

OR you put all pages in one pot and give them categories, then build the navigation by it. *This* would be a reason to change to TYPO3 6.x, as page categories are a new feature.

I haven't found an example for a category based TMENU in TYPO3 6.x quickly, so if someone might post that, it would be great.

Comment: that mount point feature looks like it is helpful, so I accepted this as answer. due to customer restrictions, an upgrade to v6 is not possible at this stage, so I will stick to the mount point feature for now. thx again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse the pages X, Y and Z, as they have different subpages. You can reuse the content: Put it into some sysfolder(s), and use the content element "insert records" to reference it on the pages.

In TYPO3 6, this content element is located in the second tab when creating new content elements. In TYPO3 4 it is somewhat hidden, you must first create a content element of some other kind and then change its type using the dropdown menu.